# Center text with higher z-index than image below (CSS)

Tags: css, text, z-index, center

I have several divs with imgs embedded. I want to put text in these divs but the text shall be above the images. So I wrote the following code:

```
#headline-div {
z-index:100;
position:absolute;
text-align: center;
}
#divbgs1 {
z-index:1;
position:relative;
} 

<div id="headline-div">
<span>Willkommen auf den Rook Islands...</span>
</div>
<div class="divbgs1">
<img src="/img/rook/img/flying.jpg"/>
</div>
```

but now the text is left to the image and i am unable to center it.
Link to the page: http://bit.ly/1i7j47A

Kind regards

Answer (score 0):

First of all you have `class="divbgs1"` in your html, but in your css you put `#divbgs1` instead of `.divbgs1`. I'm going to assume you meant for it to be a class.

```
.divbgs1 {
    text-align: center;  //add this
    z-index: 1;          //remove this
    position: relative;
    padding: 10px;       // you might want to add a padding, adjust accordingly
}

.divbgs1 img {
     position: absolute;
     top: 10px; //adjust these accordingly
     left: 10px; //adjust these accordingly
}
```

Comment: I changed it now but it still wont work. May I ask you to take a quick look at the site? :/
http://bit.ly/1i7j47A

Answer (score 0):

You can put the `#headline-div` inside the div with the image, like so

```
<div id="divbgs1">
    <div id="headline-div">
        <span>Willkommen auf den Rook Islands...</span>
    </div>
    <img src="/img/rook/img/flying.jpg">
</div>
```

then absolutely position the `#headline-div` like this

```
#headline-div {
  z-index: 100;
  position: absolute;
  text-align: center;
  width: 100%;
  margin-top: 50%;
}
```

or

you could just add

```
#headline-div {
   width: 100%;
}
```

to center the text horizontally, vertical centring requires some more effort though.

Comment: thanks a lot i srsly didnt found this css tag on any site i read.. :)

Comment: When i put the width tag in more than one class the site expands a lot to the left. Do you have another solution for this?